# Same effect in html link tag as rails 3 link_to for jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Hi
I have the following jquery to open a dialog box when link is clicked:

```
$(function() {
$( '#editdialog' ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 600,
    modal: true
});
$('#edit-dialog').click(function(){
$('#editdialog').dialog('open');
return false;
});
```

});
In the view i have

```
<%= link_to("Edit", {:controller => "projects", :action => "edit"}, {:id => "editdialog"} ) %>
```

Problem: The link does not execute the dialog box. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your id on the link is editdialog, while you're setting the click function on #edit-dialog.